# Same output in all variables

Tags: r, for-loop

I have been trying to decompose a data frame into different variables named after the title of each column.

The code bellow runs the decomposition for all columns, but the same result is output in all the variables created. I think something is wrong with the "for(j in colnames(df)" command, but I can´t figure out what.

```
for (i in 1:ncol(df))
{
    x <- (i)
    for(j in colnames(df)){
    assign(j,(stl(df[,x], s.window="periodic")))
    }
}
```

The df is structured as a time series table, each column has a name and a series of prices.

```
Serie1

Jan 2007   10.44

Feb 2007    5.75

Mar 2007    6.52

Apr 2007   13.90

May 2007   12.25

Jun 2007    7.37

Jul 2007    3.51
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#sample data
df <- data.frame(col1 = c(100:65), col2 = c(1:36))

stl_df <- list()
for(i in 1:ncol(df)){
  #convert column's data into timeseries data
  tsData = ts(df[,i],frequency = 12,start=2007)
  #calculate 'stl' and store it in a list
  stl_df[colnames(df)[i]] <- stl(tsData,s.window="periodic")
}
stl_df
```